# Intel XDK volume button events

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I'm trying to develop an app for Android and/or iPhone in Intel XDK that will do something when a volume rocker key is pressed.
Is there any way in which I can call a function when the volume up or down button is pressed, in Intel XDK?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cordova plugin available for Android.  https://github.com/manueldeveloper/cordova-plugin-volume-buttons .  You can add the plugin in the Intel XDK 3rd party plugins  https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/adding-third-party-plugins-to-your-xdk-cordova-app

I did not find an iOS compatible plugin.

Comment: I tried to use the plugin (assuming I had installed it correctly on the XDK) however it did not work after building. I used to exact sample code given on the GitHub, and made sure a deviceready event fired. Do you know of anything I should look into in particular to see why it didn't work?